# Why do I keep getting ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress when my database is open? (12c)

Tags: oracle, windows-server

I'm running Oracle on a Windows server (maybe that is why it is so buggy?). It was working fine for a bit, but lately I've been having an issue.  I keep getting the `ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress` error.

If go into the server and run SQLPlus and check the `v$instance` table it says my instance is open.  I'm able to switch to my pluggable database.  `v$database` shows  that my database is read/write.

I have a linked server set up from my MS SQL Server and it will work for awhile and then return *ORA-01033*.  So, maybe it's just SQL Server I say and try SQL Developer.  I get the same error!  Just for kicks I create a new connection on SQL Developer, and it works.  For a little while.  Then I get this: [image]

I only have ~30 GB of freespace on the drive where Oracle is loaded.  Could that be causing the issue?  If I reboot the server it works.  For a little while.  Basically, it seems to work until I start hammering on it and pulling a lot of data out.

Comment: Did you look at the alert log? Is the pdb that you are using open within the instance?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that all I know about Oracle is that I'm growing to dislike it.  So you might have to talk to me as if I were an idiot.  I found the alert_<dbname>.log file you mention, tyvm.   There is *nothing* in there from the time I am trying to connect remotely.  There are a couple of errors that are from startup though.

Yes, pdb is open.  I can query my tables from with SQLPlus and if I create a new connection in SQL Developer.

Comment: I'm getting this warning from my listener: "TNS-01199: Warning! Different databases have registered the same service".  I don't really understand it, there's not information on it out there, but could this be part of my issue?

Comment: I realized that I don't HAVE to have a pluggable database.  And it's the PDBs that have been giving me fits.  So I just dropped it and restored into a container instead and all is good so far.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why this happens, but I get such errors regularly with the pluggable database. What I do as a quick fix is I connect using sqlplus "/ as sysdba", then I run the following code for that specific database:

```
alter pluggable database orclpdb open;
```

Or the following for all databases:

```
alter pluggable database all open;
```

And I stop getting the errors for a while... until the next time it happens. :)
At least I have a quick procedure as a fix.

Comment: Do you have you pluggable database set to startup as open automatically?  If not, run this once your pluggable database is open `alter pluggable database all save state;`

shanah tovah u'metukah

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll give it a whirl.